# Connection tab of Google Cloud SQL instance taking forever to load the console interface

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to access my cloud database from my computer but the connection tab cannot load to finish so that I can enter my IPv6 address. **This is the second time am experiencing this issue and my network is strong enough**. It's now been 20 minutes, but still the three dots are just indicating progress that never ends.

The first time it happened I had to leave my computer and go for a walk. This really frustrates me since it's in production and rapid updates should not be delayed.

How can I fix this?

**POSSIBLE CAUSE:**

It happens after I **re-open** Mysql-workbench and it fails reason being my IPv6 has been changed possibly by my Internet Service Provider (ISP) (I dont know of other possible reasons). After Mysql-workbench fails, I go to the console to update the new one but this problem occurs.

**I think Cloud SQL security (don't know exact name) is treating this a malicious access attempt hence initiating this weird delay for immediate subsequent access**. If so, then this is purely **impractical** for b/s since my computer does not tell me that my IPv6 has changed, besides, that normal regular IPv6 updates can't be treated as malicious lest developers continue to suffer this issue.

**EDIT:** This time it finished loading **after approximately 50 minutes**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, otherwise I would go with Public Api + Proxy. Now I'm waiting :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) to connect to your instance instead of white-listing an IP? White-listing an IP can be insecure since it provides anyone on your network access, and inconvenient (as you have discovered) because if your IP changes you lose access.

The proxy uses a service account to provide authenticated access to your instance, so it will work regardless of your IP (as long as your service account has the correct permissions). Check out these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy) for a guide on starting it up.

(As a side note, it's a difficult problem to tell why your connectivity tab is failing to get load. It might be a browser add on or even a networking failure in your local network that is interfering. You can check the browser dev console to see if any errors appear)

Comment: Hello @kurtisvg, since I am using mysql workbench as client tool, there seem to be no way to setup auth with service account, any hints/idea?

Comment: The proxy works by listening to a local port and forwarding those connections to your instance. After setting it up, you can connect with any application (including MySQL workbench) by starting the proxy and pointing your application at `127.0.0.1:3306` (or whatever port you specify)

Comment: Great, getting down to this